# Add record button to append the row into table and refresh the form for a new record entry MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-forms

I am working on an Access Form where data entry for Table1 is performed.

- linked Table1 to this form Form1
- added 'Add Record' Button to the form
- created build event for the same to save the record.

After adding the row to the table, I want to refresh the form to its initial state so that it is ready for entering second record.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are your navigation buttons showing on your form?

Comment: Yeah they are showing in both Layout and form views.

Comment: I believe a small piece of vba code would do this trick!

Comment: Are you using code to save?

Comment: Yeah. I have used build event to save the record

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is:
At the end of your save routine, add:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Me.Name, acNewRec
```

Comment: Thanks Trevor. This helped!

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the form's *DataEntry* property to: *Yes* (True)
2. Insert this code line in the *AfterUpdate* event of the form:

   ```
   Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()    
       Me.Requery    
   End Sub
   ```